# How to disable tab switching on tab press?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, cross-platform

I am using `react-native-tab-view` for tabs.
now i have a very strange use case that i don't want user to traverse to other tabs by clicking on the tab i.e on tab press.

I want to use custom buttons on each tab to traverse back and forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.

For this, there is one prop called `onTabPress` in `TabBar` props in `react-native-tab-view`.

use the following function: `preventDefault()`.

you can do the following to disable tab click.

- **If you want to disable it for particular tab than...**

> ```
> <TabBar onTabPress={({ route, preventDefault }) => {
>      // here `route.key` will be your particular tab's route key
>      if (route.key === 'home') {
>        preventDefault();
>
>       // Do something else
>      }   
>     }} 
>     ... 
>     />
> ```

- **If you want to disable tab click for all the tabs.**

  > ```
  >    <TabBar
  >    {...props}
  >    onTabPress={({preventDefault}) => {
  >     preventDefault();
  >    }}
  >    />
  > ```

**Note: This will work with react navigation as well. Attaching the link:** https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/

Comment: wait, have you solved it ?

Comment: Yes ! i have solved it @GauravRoy

Comment: @GauravRoy it is working like charm

Comment: stackoverflow as blogs

Comment: Yeahhh :) Hope this will happy many
@GauravRoy not like blogs friend
just helping others so that they don't waste the precious time like i did